# How can i call generic T type method in c#

Tags: c#

I have method

```
public static T GetUrlDataEntity<T>(){}
```

and i want to call this method in my another class how can i call this method in c#.

Comment: Try to constrain T, take a look here for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify a type argument. For example:

```
string x = TypeDeclaringMethod.GetUrlDataEntity<string>();
```

The [MSDN documentation on generic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) has more details.

Note that in this case, you *can't* use type inference as the method has no parameters which use `T`. If your method were:

```
public static T DoSomething<T>(T input)
```

then you'd be able to get the compiler to infer the type argument, e.g.

```
int x = 10;
int y = DoSomething(x);
```

Comment: Jon Skeet is on the watch even on weekends! :D

Comment: Thank you i used here string id =URLHelper.GetUrlDataEntity<string>();